# Updating a record in SQLite using a Spinner value as the WHERE clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this:

[image]

I have a spinner that provides choices of employees taken from SQLite database. I'm trying to update the record by using the option selected as the where value. For example, if Lysandros Lysandrou is selected, then that record with the corresponding name should be updated in the database.

My research has got me here so far:

The code is working but no actual update is happening. How can I achieve the update?

My spinner:

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    //database handler
    LysandrosDatabaseAdapter db = new LysandrosDatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    //spinner drop down elements
    List<DataBean> list = db.getAllDat();
    String[] nameList = new String[list.size()];

    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        nameList[i] = list.get(i).getName() + " " + list.get(i).getSurname();

    }
    //creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String > dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, nameList);
    //drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //attaching data adapter to spinner
    SelectName.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

My DataBean class:

```
public class DataBean {

//employee fields
protected int id;
protected String name;
protected String surname;
protected String department;
protected String workplace;

public DataBean (int id, String name, String surname, String department, String workplace ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.department = department;
    this.workplace = workplace;
}

public DataBean (String name, String surname, String department, String workplace, String absentName, String absenceStartdate, String absenceEnddate, String absenceNotes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.department = department;
    this.workplace = workplace;

}

public int getID() {
    return this.id;
}

public int setID(int id) { return this.id = id; }

public String getName() {
    return this. name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return this.surname;
}

public String getDepartment() {
    return this.department;
}

public String getWorkplace() {
   return this.workplace;
}
```

Please bear with me as I'm new to Android and Java. What am I missing? I'm thinking it might be something with my WHERE clause but I can't know. Also, I think I've included everything needed but if you require anything else please let me know.

EDIT 2: My database class:

```
public class LysandrosDatabaseAdapter {

LysandrosHelper helper;

public LysandrosDatabaseAdapter (Context context) {

    helper = new LysandrosHelper(context);
}

public long insertData (String name,
                        String surname,
                        String tnumber,
                        String bnumber,
                        String email,
                        String address,
                        String dob,
                        String department,
                        String managerid,
                        String workplace,
                        String stardate,
                        String notes)

{
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.SURNAME, surname);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.NUMBER, tnumber);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.BNUMBER, bnumber);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.EMAIL, email);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.ADDRESS, address);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.DOB, dob);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.DEPARTMENT, department);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.MANAGERID, managerid);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.WORKPLACE, workplace);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.STARTDATE, stardate);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.NOTES, notes);


    long id = db.insert(LysandrosHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return id;
}

public int updateEmployee(String nameupdate,
                          String surnameupdate,
                          String departmentupdate,
                          String workplaceupdate) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.NAME, nameupdate);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.SURNAME, surnameupdate);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.DEPARTMENT, departmentupdate);
    contentValues.put(LysandrosHelper.WORKPLACE, workplaceupdate);

    return db.update(LysandrosHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, LysandrosHelper.NAME + " = ?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(DataBean.class.getName())});
}

static class LysandrosHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //database info and version
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LysandrosDatabase";
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "LysandrosTable";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

    //employees info
    static final String UID = "_id";
    static final String NAME = "Name";
    static final String SURNAME = "Surname";
    static final String NUMBER = "TelephoneNumber";
    static final String BNUMBER = "BusinessNumber";
    static final String EMAIL = "Email";
    static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
    static final String DOB = "DateofBirth";
    static final String DEPARTMENT = "Department";
    static final String WORKPLACE = "Workplace";
    static final String MANAGERID = "ManagerID";
    static final String STARTDATE = "StartDate";
    static final String NOTES = "Notes";

    //absences info
    static final String ABSENTNAME = "AbsentName";
    static final String ABSENCESTARTDATE = "AbsenceStartDate";
    static final String ABSENCEENDDATE = "AbsenceEndDate";
    static final String ABSENCENOTES = "AbsenceNotes";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            ""+NAME+" VARCHAR(255), " +
            ""+SURNAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+
            ""+NUMBER+" INTEGER," +
            ""+BNUMBER+" INTEGER," +
            ""+EMAIL+" VARCHAR(255)," +
            ""+ADDRESS+" VARCHAR(255)," +
            ""+DOB+" DATE," +
            ""+DEPARTMENT+" VARCHAR(255)," +
            ""+WORKPLACE+" VARCHAR(255)," +
            ""+MANAGERID+" INTEGER," +
            ""+STARTDATE+" DATE," +
            ""+ABSENTNAME+" VARCHAR(255)," +
            ""+ABSENCESTARTDATE+" DATE," +
            ""+ABSENCEENDDATE+" DATE," +
            ""+ABSENCENOTES+" TEXT,"+
            ""+NOTES+" TEXT);";
```

Comment: where is your db.update() method?

Comment: I've added the code, I assume that was what you were looking for?

Comment: the db.update() is mentioned already mate

Comment: where is the code for LysandrosHelper and have logged all the values out to see if any are null?

Comment: Check my edit, I've put the code from the database. And no I don't think so. But when I do a normal search on my database, I get the old data back.

Comment: new String[] {String.valueOf()} is this part correct?

Comment: christ sorry, i was editing my code when i posted the question. It's fixed now

Comment: Add correct code and accept the answer for others, I hope I helped

Comment: No sorry, I meant my edit is fixed not my code..if you check again that sentenced is finished now. That's how the whole code is, and it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is use raw Queries AS I find them much easier to debug. so try

```
 String updateSql =  "UPDATE " + LysandrosHelper.TABLE_NAME +" Set " + LysandrosHelper.DEPARTMENT + " = " + departmentupdate + ","+LysandrosHelper.WORKPLACE +" = "+ workplaceupdate +" WHERE "+ LysandrosHelper.NAME +" ="+ nameupdate +" AND +" LysandrosHelper.SURNAME +" = "+surnameupdate +";"

// then 
db.exec(updateSql);
```

should work, don’t forget the semicolon at the end of the statement, and I would urge you to consider giving each user a unique id in the database. the store this somewhere in your form and reference the updates via user id. String compares are slower and far more prone to errors IMHO

Comment: In that case consider adding a hidden field with the uid and change the where clause to "WHERE UID = " +uid+ " ;";